# Refinement filter to look at the Title and Path properties with REST Search API

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api

I have a POST search using the following select properties:

Path,Title,Size,Author,Description,FileExtension,Rank,DocId,WorkId,ParentLink,FileType,ServerRedirectedEmbedURL,ServerRedirectedPreviewURL,ServerRedirectedURL,HitHighlightedSummary

And using this RefinementFilter:
title:or("doc1","doc2","doc3","doc4".....)

If I pass in 10 files to be filtered in the title:or I may get back 7 of them.  So looking at the three that are missing, I find that the title of the document is not the same as the path.  So the pay may be:

> Path: https://[server]/Path/documentX.pdf

but the Title will be:

> Title: This is document X

For some reason the Title and the path to the file are not the same.  So, I need to modify the refinement filter to look in Path: to pull out the file names instead of the title.  I did try Path:or(list of files) but I get no results. Then I tried adding a star (*) before and/or after the title still with no luck:

Path:or("*filename*","*file2*")

I need something like a "contains" clause that would look in the full path for the document title for a search.  Can this be done?

Thanks.